# Connection attempt from disallowed node 'ejabberdctl-1@localhost'

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

The title is what appears in my ejabberd log files after an unsuccessful start.  I did some googling and have noticed it is probably related to my cookies..

Running get_cookie() in the erlang shell prints 'nocookie'.  Is this typical for a fresh install of erlang?  How should I ideally go about setting the cookie?

Answer (score 1):

`nocookie` would likely mean that the node hasn't been started in distributed mode. All distributed nodes otherwise have a cookie.

You will have to make sure your node is started in distributed mode (through `-name` or `-sname` arguments) for things to work.

In case the node is already started *and* you have access to a shell, you can start the distributed kernel by hand with `net_kernel:start([Name, shortnames])` or `net_kernel:start([Name, longnames])`.